# How to select all the checkboxes on one click?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to select all the checkbox values on one click, I have used the same thing in another project few months ago, where it is working fine, but now here it is not working.

Here is the code:

```
<tbody> 
<span style="margin-left:0px;">Select All &nbsp;    <input type="checkbox"  name="foo"  onClick="checkall(this)">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="submit" value="delete" name="delete"></span>               
<?php
if ($allTemplates > 0): $sr = '1';
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($allTemplates)):

        ?>        
        <tr>
            <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" name="foo[]" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" /><?php echo $sr; ?>. </td>
            <td class="hidden-phone" style='text-align:center;'><?php echo $row['on_date']; ?></td>
            <td class="hidden-phone" style='text-align:center;'><a  href="javascript:Show('#.php?id=<? echo $row['template_id']?>')"><?php echo $row['template_id']; ?></a></td>                        
            <td class="hidden-phone"><?php echo ucfirst($row['title']); ?></td>
            <td class="hidden-phone" style='text-align:center;'><a  href="javascript:Show('profile_lady.php?id=<? echo $row['user_id']?>')"><?php echo $row['user_id']; ?></a></td>
            <td class="hidden-phone" style='text-align:center;'><?php echo ucfirst($record['fname']) . ' ' . $record['lname']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        $sr++;
    endwhile;
endif;

?>
</tbody>
```

And here is the function I used:

```
<script language = "JavaScript" >
    function checkall(source) {
        checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('foo[]');
        for (var i = 0, n = checkboxes.length; i < n; i++) {
            checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
        }
    } 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var elems= document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i =0; i < elems.length; i++){
        if (elems[i].type == 'checkbox')
            elems[i].checked = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your javascript with this:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function checkall(source) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('foo[]');
  for(i=0,i< checkboxes.length;i++) {
  checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
  }
  }</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function checkall(source) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('foo[]');
  if (checked == false) {
      checked = true
  }
  else {
      checked = false
  }
  for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
      if(checkboxes[i].type== 'checkbox') {
          checkboxes[i].checked = checked;  
      }
  }
</script>
```